# Apply default mapping to mock Mongo domains in Grails unit test

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I've started using the new mocking support in grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb. My app defaults domain mappings to use references when persisting relationships to mongodb.  I need to find a way to get the mocked mongo to do the same thing.  How do I apply the same default mapping in a unit test?

In Config.groovy, it looks like this:

```
// configure mongo to use dbrefs:
grails.mongo.default.mapping = { 
  '*'(reference: true)
}
```

Here's a sample of code that I currently use:

```
import spock.lang.*
import grails.test.mixin.mongodb.MongoDbTestMixin
import com.github.fakemongo.Fongo

@Mixin([MongoDbTestMixin])
class MySpec extends Specification {
  def setup() {
    mongoDomain(new Fongo("test").mongo, [ MyDomain ])
    new MyDomain(name: 'domain').save(validate: false, flush: true)
  }
}
```

How do I apply that config to this test code?

I'm using Grails 2.3.9 and mongodb 3.0.1 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `MongoDbTestMixin` offers a few flavors of the `mongoDomain` method:

1. `mongoDomain(Mongo mongo, Collection<Class> persistentClasses)` - Sets up a GORM for MongoDB domain for the given Mongo instance and domain classes
2. `mongoDomain(Map config, Collection<Class> persistentClasses)` - Sets up a GORM for MongoDB domain for the given configuration and domain classes

The 2nd option allows to pass a configuration map which allows to configure mongo to use dbrefs (otherwise an empty configuration is used, see [MongoDbDataStoreSpringInitializer](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb/src/main/groovy/grails/mongodb/bootstrap/MongoDbDataStoreSpringInitializer.groovy) ). However this method does not allow you to pass the Fongo instance.

You can try to:

1. Ask the Grails team to add a method which combines both options (pull request?)
2. Extend [MongoDbTestMixin](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb/src/main/groovy/grails/test/mixin/mongodb/MongoDbTestMixin.groovy) or create your own mixin